# Are the Chunin exams always held in Konoha?

Tags: naruto

I know that all of the villages now hold their Chunin exams together and have since the Third Ninja World War. The only two in-canon Chunin exam that have been seen, however, were held in Konoha. Are all Chunin exams held in Konoha? If not, how is it decided where they are held?

Comment: There have actually been two in-canon exams. Obito, Kakashi, Guy and the others from that batch took part in the other.

Comment: I think it was specifically said that it's held in different villages each time and that it only happened to be held in Konoha at this time.

Answer (score 4):

**EDITED:**
According to [www.naruto2.com](http://www.naruto2.com/Information/Naruto-ChuuninExam.aspx), no. It can be held in different ninja villages as well. And because of convenience purposes, the village with the most participating ninjas will host the Chuunin Exams.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add the reference. I've already edited my answer. 

I was thinking of Kiri's Deathmatch Exam that Sabuza won after killing his classmates. That's why I answered 'No'. But on second thought, it's just a Genin Exam, not a Chuunin. My bad. You can downvote me if you're not satisfied with the reference..XD